# Find unique identifier of CSS Stylesheet in Prestashop registered with addCSS()

Tags: prestashop

I am working on a module custom module for a specific website that helps with render-blocking resources. This module unregisters render-blocking files using unregisterStylesheet, then registers them again with the media="print" value.

Just like this:

```
$this->context->controller->unregisterStylesheet('css_file_unique_identifier');
```

In order to use unregisterStylesheet to unregister a CSS file, I need to specify the unique identifier that has been assigned to it, but the problem comes when the CSS files have been registered with addCSS() function, which seems to not require to assign a unique ID for that CSS file.

This is how the CSS file is registered on its module, and the one I cant catch to unregister:

```
$this->media->addCSS(array(
'views/css/front/dp-cart-summary.css'
), $css_base_path);
```

I have tried to unregister the file by just trying to "wonder" the ID, but I didnt manage to do so.

Question: **How can I find which default value that Prestashop has assigned to that CSS file?**